# Mongodb error: failed to open "/var/mongodb/db/node1/mongod.log"

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run the following configuration file (called node1.conf) in order to start up a replica set:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/node1
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.103.100,localhost
  port: 27011
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /var/mongodb/pki/m103-keyfile
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/mongodb/db/node1/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
replication:
  replSetName: m103-example
```

As you may see, mongod should sends logs to the following route: */var/mongodb/db/node1/mongod.log*. However, when running this config file I get this error message:

[image]

If anyone has any clue about what is happening I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **user(mongodb) and permissions** for your defined log path.

First check the user and given permission :

`ls -lh /var/log/mongodb/`  or /YourDefinedLogPath

If needs to change user or permission you may try

**`sudo chown mongodb /var/log/mongodb`** or your defined log folder.

After applying these changes restart the mongod service.

**`sudo systemctl restart mongod`**

Comment: sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: You may check the mongod service status using this command,

 sudo service mongod status